# Which one of these german paragraphs is correct and why?

Tags: word-order, comma

I'm learning German so I tried to translate and write these two paragraphs but I still don't know how to use "dass" with comma.
So I need your help, which one is correct and why?

The first Paragraph:

> Hiermit wird bestättigt, dass Frau.  Karl Maria von Weber, Matrikelnummer: 321, die vorgeschriebenen Kurse für die akademischen Jahre 2002-2007 abschloss, alle Voraussetzunge für den akadimischen Grad Bachelor  in  „Zahnmedizin“ erfüllte und mit der Gesamtnote (Sehr gut) bestand.

The second Paragraph:

> Hiermit wird bestättigt, dass Frau.  Karl Maria von Weber, Matrikelnummer: 321, die vorgeschriebenen Kurse für die akademischen Jahre 2002-2007 abschloss, **dass** alle Voraussetzunge für den akadimischen Grad Bachelor  in  „Zahnmedizin“ erfüllte und **dass** mit der Gesamtnote (Sehr gut) bestand.

Comment: Was soll der Punkt nach _Frau_? Der Doppelpunkt nach Matr.Nr. gehört da auch nicht hin, akad_i_mischen ist falsch, _bestätigt_ ohne doppel-t Zahnmedizin ist weder direkte Rede, noch ein Zitat, sondern der Name des Fachs, der hier zu erwarten ist und daher weg mit den Anführungszeichen, wie auch die Klammer um das _Sehr gut_ verstörend wirkt. Ansonsten ist Abs. 1 richtig aber wir machen hier kein Proofreading und daher schlage ich das Schließen vor. Die Mehrzahl von _Vorraussetzung_ bitte auch noch überprüfen.

Comment: Außerdem ist Maria ein relativ häufiger Beiname für Männer, Karl aber nicht für Frauen. Für Firefox, Chromium u.a. gibt es Rechtschreibkorrekturen, die über die Hälfte der Fehler finden.

Comment: @userunknown Der hat in deinem Kommentar aber leider die *Voraussetzungen* nicht unterringelt ;-p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the errors found by "user unknown" the second sentence is (more) wrong (than the first one):

You can use the "*dass*" three times but in this case you would need to use a subject in all three relative clauses:

> Hiermit wird bestä**t**igt, dass Frau **Andrea** Maria von Weber, Matrikelnummer: 321, die vorgeschriebenen Kurse für die akademischen Jahre 2002-2007 abschloss, dass ***sie*** alle Voraussetzunge**n** für den akad**e**mischen Grad Bachelor in „Zahnmedizin“ erfüllte und dass ***sie*** mit der Gesamtnote **„Sehr gut“** bestand.

(My spell checker found some more spelling errors which I marked in bold.)

To explain one of the points in "user unknown"'s comment: The mark "*sehr gut*" is typically not written in brackets but in quotation marks.

However the first sentence is better style.

Another problem is that you would not write such a sentence in "Präteritum" tense but in "Perfekt" tense:

> Hiermit wird bestätigt, dass Frau Andrea Maria von Weber, Matrikelnummer: 321, die vorgeschriebenen Kurse für die akademischen Jahre 2002-2007 **abgeschlossen**, alle Voraussetzungen für den akademischen Grad Bachelor in „Zahnmedizin“ **erfüllt** und mit der Gesamtnote „Sehr gut“ **bestanden hat**.

Comment: Wenn Du Kurse in Zahnmedizin belegst, setzt Du es dann auch in Anführungsstrich? Oder einen Kurs in "Yoga"? Wozu? Was soll das Ausdrücken? Spott? Bei "Alternativmedizin" würde ich 's verstehen.

Comment: Deinem Rechtschreibprüfprogramm traue ich nicht mehr, wenn es aus »Frau Karl« lieber »Frau Andrea« als »Herr Karl« macht …

Comment: @userunknown Ich habe diese Schreibweise bereits gelesen; die Schreibweise mit den Klammern jedoch nicht.

Comment: When I translate a certificate I have to write it in perfect.

Comment: @Nafmee Gute Frage. Allerdings kann mand die Anführungszeichen bei "Sehr gut" erklären, dass man so "sehr gut" nicht als adverbiales Adjektiv im Satz "... und mit der Gesamtnote bestanden hat" verstehen kann.

Comment: @MartinRosenau: Ich habe auch schon sehr viel gelesen. Das kann kein Maßstab sein. Wenn es herausstechen soll, dann setzt man es, wenn es das Medium erlaubt, fett. Beim _Sehr gut_ sieht die Sache in der Tat einen Deut anders aus; es könnte auch bedeuten 'mit der Gesamtnote _sehr_ gut bestanden hat - das ist aber vom Kontext eigentlich auch ausgeschlossen. Die Auszeichnung kann die Satzerfassung leicht verbessern so dass ich das nicht ankreiden würde; ich würde es aber von mir aus nicht machen. Nach "... und mit der Gesamtnote ..." - was soll da kommen, wenn nicht die Note? Ein eingesch. NSatz.